# .php exstension not removed via .htaccess on some pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was hoping someone can assist. I am using the following to remove the `.php` extension from my URLs via *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I am now able to access most of the URLs without the `.php` extension, but not all of them, some URLs are resolving 404s.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you give some specific examples instead of the nebulous "some"?

Comment: Ok, I can access the URL below with or without the .php extension 

https://www.freshearth.co.uk/vegan-breakfast
https://www.freshearth.co.uk/vegan-breakfast.php

But not this one:
https://www.freshearth.co.uk/united-kingdom/london/vegan-restaurants.php
https://www.freshearth.co.uk/united-kingdom/london/vegan-restaurants

Comment: Do folders like `united-kingdom` or `united-kingdom/london` exist in the physical file system? In that case your setting for the AcceptPathInfo directive might interfere here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

Comment: Thank you! Yes they do